# MQL4 How to call OnChartEvent() from init()

Tags: mql4

I want to call `OnChartEvent()` from `init()` like the code below, so the EA should process first the password and then the rest of the code.

I am just newbie not an expert in coding.

The idea or objective, the password must enter first and correctly, after successful then process the rest of code.

```
#include <ChartObjects/ChartObjectsTxtControls.mqh>

int init()
{
    password_edit.Create(0, "password_edit", 0, 10, 10, 260, 25);
    password_edit.BackColor(White);
    password_edit.BorderColor(Black);
}

//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| ChartEvent function                                              |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
void OnChartEvent( const int id,
                   const long &lparam,
                   const double &dparam,
                   const string &sparam
                   )
{
//---
  if (id == CHARTEVENT_OBJECT_ENDEDIT && sparam == "password_edit" )
  {
     password_status = -1;

     for (int i=0; i<ArraySize(allowed_passwords); i++)
        if (password_edit.GetString(OBJPROP_TEXT) ==   allowed_passwords[i]) 
           {
              password_status = i;
              break;
           }

        if (password_status == -1) 
           {
              password_edit.SetString(OBJPROP_TEXT, 0, password_message[0]);
              ExpertRemove(); 

           }
        else 
           {
              password_edit.SetString(OBJPROP_TEXT, 0, password_message[1]);
           } 
  }
}
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int OnInit(){
    passwordOperation();
    return INIT_SUCCEED;
}

void OnChartEvent(const int id,
              const long &lparam,
              const double &dparam,
              const string &sparam)
{
//---
if (id == CHARTEVENT_OBJECT_ENDEDIT && sparam == "password_edit" )
  {
    passwordOperation();
  }
}

void passwordOperation()
   {
     password_status = -1;

     for (int i=0; i<ArraySize(allowed_passwords); i++)
        if (password_edit.GetString(OBJPROP_TEXT) ==   allowed_passwords[i]) 
           {
              password_status = i;
              break;
           }

        if (password_status == -1) 
           {
              password_edit.SetString(OBJPROP_TEXT, 0, password_message[0]);
              ExpertRemove(); 
           }
        else 
           {
              password_edit.SetString(OBJPROP_TEXT, 0, password_message[1]);
           }    
   }
```

Comment: hi Daniel Kniaz, thank you very much for your response, i have edited the my question, could you give me advice ? the idea/object, password must entry first and successful, then the process the rest of code. without password, the program cannot run. thanks

Comment: I do not think that you need a password check in `OnInit()`. Create the GUI object and declare a `int password_status` globally. If password in entered, check it (in OnChartEvent) and change password_status, otherwise do not allow any other options until that is done